# Android: Making Volley HTTP Requests in the background

Tags: android, api, http, android-volley, background-process

I am using Volley to make HTTP Calls in my android app. I have a requirement to poll a server every 5 seconds. This should happen even when the app is minimized(or when another app is opened). I am getting timeout errors when the app is minimized and you are on the Home Screen.

here is the code I am using.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
...
<service android:name=".webviews.services.ScheduledService" android:enabled="true"></service>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

ScheduledService.java

```
package com.magic.ultimate_android.webviews.services;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.ToneGenerator;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class ScheduledService extends Service
{

    Timer timer;

    private static final String TAG = "ScheduledService";
    String valueFromURL = "";
    int requestCount = 0;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "On Bind called");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "On Create called");
        super.onCreate();

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "On Start Command called");

        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals("START_TIMER")) {
            String urlInput = “https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1”;
            String field = “title”;
            Log.d(TAG, "Start Timer now******");
            startTimer(urlInput, field);
        } else if (action.equals("STOP_TIMER")) {
            stopTimer();
        }


        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void stopTimer() {
        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
        }
    }

    private void startTimer(final String urlInput, final String field) {
        timer = new Timer();
        requestCount = 0;
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               Log.d(TAG, "URL Input: " + urlInput + ", Field: " + field);
                makeServiceCall(urlInput, field);

            }
        }, 0, 5000);
    }

    private void makeServiceCall(final String urlInput, final String field) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Making Service call...");

        RequestQueue requestQueue = getRequestQueue();
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, urlInput, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "start of response");


                    if (!response.has(field)) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if ((String) response.get(field).equals(("TARGET_VALUE"))) {
                        makeServiceCall(urlInput, field);
                        
                    } else {
                        
                            if (timer != null) {
                                timer.cancel();
                                Log.d(TAG, "Timer is cancelled");
                            }
                            // TODO: SEND MESSAGE TO UPDATE THE APP
                            Intent intent = new Intent(“MESSAGE_TO_MAIN_APP");
                            // You can also include some extra data.                            
                            getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);                        
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                error.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, error.toString());
                makeServiceCall(urlInput, field);
            }
        });
        jsonObjectRequest.setShouldCache(false);
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);



    }

    private RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (requestQueue == null) {
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        }
        return requestQueue;
    }

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScheduledService.class);
intent.setAction("START_TIMER");
startService(intent);
```

When the app is open and running, the code works perfectly fine. I see both the logs
Making Service Calls
start of response

But when the app is minimized, I see only the first one. And a volley error
com.android.volley.TimeoutError

Can you please help?

Comment: You may want to edit your question and post the full stack trace of your error. Note that your service will be stopped after a minute on Android 8.0+. You would need to make it a foreground service to avoid that. And that will not avoid Doze mode and similar battery saving approaches.

Comment: Your requirements are not going to be possible on current Android devices.  And probably wouldn't be a good idea anyway as your app scales to more users, given that level of traffic.  I'd look for better ways to get the information you actually need, rather than constant server requests.

Comment: It's a unique requirement and is a private app for a small set of users. So am not concerned very much about the scalability and the performance.